# How can I add a custom parameter to a URI in spring webflow 1.5

Tags: spring-webflow

My marketing people want me to include a custom parameter in the URI string for certain pages so they can be tracked by Google analytics. But all of the pages they want to track are pages controlled by Spring Webflow (1.5), which generates the URLS and redirects to them. Is there a class I can override or something i can add to the flow definition file that will allow me to add params such as "order=complete" or "design=complete" etc?

It looks as though RequestPathFlowExecutorArgumentHandler would have been a good candidate for getting this done, but it seems that it was removed in 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been facing the same problem and finally switched to parameters inside Google Analytics javascript call, eg:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'account-id']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'order', 'complete']);
```